# jquery mobile mvc RadioButtonFor vb.net grouping name issue

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile with asp.net mvc in vb trying to render a yes/no radio button group:

```
@For Each fqi In Model.Options

                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.CurrentValue, fqi.Value)
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.CurrentValue, fqi.Checked)

     Next
```

But it doesn't render properly

when comparing with regular jquerymobile radio button group, I noticed that the html behind is adding additional div tag of `<div class="ui-radio">`

How do I use the radiobuttonfor correctly to work properly with jquerymobile?

I've researched and play around and I know that if I just use below, it will work. But I need to use the radiobuttonfor tag....

```
If Model.IsRadioList Then
    @<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    @For Each fqi In Model.Options


                    @<label for="@fqi.Value">@fqi.Text</label>
                    @<input type="radio" name="@fqi.Name" id="@fqi.value" value="@fqi.Value" />

     Next

        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

It was just logic issue on using different classes. I doubt that anyone will stumble in this issue

Comment: So you're saying that you doubt that anyone will EVER have this issue?  Unless you're extraordinarily stupid, I seriously think people will have the issue you have.